# Jupyter Notebook %matplotlib inline Not Working

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Jupyter notebook for the first time and following tutorials, but I'm having trouble getting plots to actually draw. I'm using the %matplotlib inline command, and its not giving me an error, but it's not drawing any plots either.

My notebook is:

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]:
df = pd.read_csv('election results.csv', index_col='ons_id')
In [3]:
df['valid_votes-2015'].plot
Out[3]:
<pandas.tools.plotting.SeriesPlotMethods object at 0x000002B03AFEF6A0>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **call** `plot()`:

```
df['valid_votes-2015'].plot()
```

You just get the method object `plot` with:

```
df['valid_votes-2015'].plot
```

but you need to make it do something with the added parenthesis.